# Algebras for the codensity monad

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given a functor $j : A \to B$, when this extension exists we call $T_j = Ran_jj$ the *codensity monad* of $j$.

I was wondering if there's a general rule to guess the shape of $Alg(T_j)$ given $j$.